# Excel formulas for frequency tables

Tags: excel, frequency

Any straightforward Excel formula to calculate the average (mode, stdev,...) for data in a frequency table like this:

```
value    frequency
5         3
8         5
4         11
....      ....
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, I know this, but this does not apply on frequency table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the native statistical worksheet functions, you are going to have to expand your frequency table into an array of numbers. While google spreadsheets has the textjoin and split functions to create an array, excel has no such native capability.

Use a User Defined Function to expand the frequency table into an array of its elements.

```
Function freqArray(rngV As Range, rngF As Range, _
                   Optional bSorted As Long = 0)
    'usage: =freqArray(<value_range>, <frequency_range>, <-1 descending; 0 no sort (default); 1 ascending> 

    Set rngV = Intersect(rngV, rngV.Parent.UsedRange)
    Set rngF = rngF.Cells(1).Resize(rngV.Rows.Count, rngV.Columns.Count)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ReDim fa(1 To rngV.Rows.Count * Application.Sum(rngF))

    For i = 1 To rngV.Cells.Count
        For j = 1 To rngF.Cells(i).Value
            k = k + 1
            fa(k) = rngV.Cells(i)
        Next j
    Next i

    If bSorted Then
        Dim tmp As Variant, bDescending As Boolean
        bDescending = CBool(bSorted < 0)
        For i = LBound(fa) To UBound(fa) - 1
            For j = i + 1 To UBound(fa)
                If CBool(fa(i) < fa(j) And bDescending) Xor _
                   CBool(fa(i) > fa(j) And Not bDescending) Then
                    tmp = fa(j): fa(j) = fa(i): fa(i) = tmp
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If

    freqArray = fa

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: very nice approach

Comment: Actually all just bits and pieces I had lying around and threw together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Excel's native statistical functions by passing the following (you have to commit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
IF(Table1[frequency]>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(Table1[frequency])))),Table1[value])
```

[image]

Comment: I think this will only work if the number of rows in the table>=max frequency i.e. it doesn't give the correct result with the first 3 rows from OP.

Comment: Thanks @TomSharpe! My formula had a `MAX` in it when I wrote it in my head, then I couldn't remember why when I wrote it down. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For average:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4*B2:B4)/SUM(B2:B4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So following a similar pattern to @Gary's Student's, the (sample) variance Var1 is

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4^2*B2:B4)-SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4*B2:B4)^2/SUM(B2:B4))/(SUM(B2:B4)-1)
```

The (sample) standard deviation SD1 is the square root of this.

Uses the alternate formula for variance and SD:

[image]

Borrowing again from another answer @jblood94, you could get the variance Var2 and standard deviation SD2 with

```
=VAR.S(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDEX(A1:INDEX(A:A,MAX(B2:B4)),0)))<=B2:B4,A2:A4,""))


=STDEV.S(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDEX(A1:INDEX(A:A,MAX(B2:B4)),0)))<=B2:B4,A2:A4,""))
```

etc.

[image]

Clearly because this produces a 2d array (3 rows and 11 columns for the sample data) it can need a lot more storage than the VBA solution.